# Suggestion in interfacing CT to microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, adc, transformer

I am working on interfacing CT to PIC 18f4550 controller. Please find below my rough circuit diagram. my questions are

i)the Recommended Secondary Burden is 47 ohm. i have used in my circuit as 200 ohm is it advisable?

ii) is the below circuit is reliable and better way for  interface with micro controller

iii)is there any modifications can be done to make it better?

I am using electrohms CT-1169 max i/p 60A rms,turns 1:7000,suggested burden resistor 47 ohm
for datasheet [1] http://www.electrohms.com/data_pdf/CT1169_01.PDF

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdAuYO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Read the small print at the bottom of the brochure

Answer (score 3):

Some remarks:

- when 47 Ohm is recommended, why choose 200 Ohm??
- IIRC the recommended maximum source impedance for the A/D is 2.5k, the DC impedance of your devider is 5k. If power is not a problem I would take two 1k resistors.
- that direct line from the trafo to the A/D input pin makes me nervous. I would add a series resistor (1k) and two (schottky) diodes for protection, and maybe a capacitor too.

For an explanation of resistor-diode-diode for input protection read [what-kind-of-diode-to-use-with-adc-inputs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45127/what-kind-of-diode-to-use-with-adc-inputs/45145#45145).

Comment: i have now understood  the importance of source impedance, if source impedance of adc is greater than  2.5 will affect the  acquisition time.ya surely  i will change it to 2.5k .1) I didn't understood importance of burden resistance , will increasing the value, affect my performance/resolution ???.2)what's c1 capacitor value i should choose ?. 3) if possible could u so some example to use schokkty diode & capacitor  to adc input to improve my understanding

Comment: FWIW, the AC source impedance of the input to the MCU ADC will have a much lower impedance, depending on the capacitance of C1. If he's not running the ADC continuously, it'll *probably* be fine.

Comment: True, but no value for C1 is shown, so I can't rely on it.